# Is Metallica's lyrics considered to be great by native speakers?

Tags: lyrics, metallica

I'm not a native English speaker so despite I'm able to understand what a particular song lyrics is about I can't determine how good it is in terms of poetry. I'm well aware that for instance Bob Dylan and The Rolling Stones are considered to be legendary poets by native speakers but I have always been wondering what degree of acknowledgement Metallica receives for its lyrics alone. Is Metallica's lyrics great, mediocre or primitive?

Comment: agree with @VikingChildren.  Also would not say the Rolling Stones are poets.

Comment: Subjective. Without risking to piss any fans off too much, you could perhaps compare the quality of Metallica lyrics in general versus the quality of lyrics in covers performed by Metallica. 

Some covers with excellent lyrics that stand out in various ways: _Whiskey in the Jar_, _Turn the Page_, _Brothers in Arms_, _Stone Cold Crazy_. Compare these with for example any of the lyrics of the Black Album, all written by Metallica. IMO the latter ain't even playing in the same division lyrics-wise and yet this is considered one of their best albums. I dare say it ain't because of the lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

It's opinion based, honestly. I would say Metallica's strength is not in the lyrics. The lyrics are primitive for lack of a better word. There's not much subtext to draw from their lyrics, and most of the rhyming schemes are basic ABAB. That isn't to say they aren't 'good', but Metallica aren't know for lyrical sophistication.